Couple moves to new house and a young neigbour falls for the wife
I cannot for the life of me remember this movie and I can't find it anywhere. Can someone help me please. It's a scary movie.
All I know is that it's a young couple that moves into a new house and the neighbor is a young guy that falls for the wife. The only other part I remember is that thing started happening so she installed security cameras into the house. She got pregnant and it wasn't from her husband because he was sterile he had found out. So he thought she was cheating. So she looked on the security cameras and sees her neighbor come into her room, kill her, have sex with her, and then like breathes her soul back into her and she comes back to life. 

Come Back to Me (2014)

Sarah and Josh are married suburbanites. After a car accident, Sarah suffers blackouts. As her life spirals she hides a camera in her home and unlocks a horrific secret with far-reaching consequences.

Wikipedia
